# How to make a hierarchical sidebar in SwiftUI where the sub-elements are a different type than the parents?

Tags: swift, cocoa, swiftui

I am trying to make a similar hierarchical sidebar to the macOS Mail app using SwiftUI,
Where you have parent elements, like "All Sent" and then child elements like individual mail boxes, and unlike the typical List header style, the parent elements are themselves selectable.
[Example of hiarchical sidebar, from the macOS mail app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOUwn.png)

I've looked around for solutions to this and the only ones I could find were with the parent and child elements using the same swift type, but I need something that works with different ones, for example with a list of mail servers, which has a list of folders as children.

```swift
struct MailServer {
  let id: UUID
  let name: String
  let folders: [MailServerFolder] = []
}

struct MailServerFolder {
  let id: UUID
  let name: String
  let items: [Message]
}

struct TestView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List(servers) { server in
      Section(content: {
            ForEach(server.folders) { folder in
                Text(channel.name)
            }
        }, header: {
            HStack {
                Text(server.name)
            }
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if there is a way to do this in SwiftUI, or if an AppKit based solution is necessary.

Comment: Refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup Just wrap `OutlineGroup` inside a `List`. Trick is to represent parent and child types in a common type and represent them. This is just to manage the views, the underlying types could be different too, just need a way to map them

Comment: Create a protocol that both the parent and child conforms to and then use that protocol as the element type for your data source (`servers`)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to user1046037 and Joakim Danielson for the help!
Based on their suggestions I went with this solution which works great

```swift
struct ServerListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    @FetchRequest(
            entity: ServerEntry.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: []
    ) var serverEntries: FetchedResults<ServerEntry>
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            OutlineGroup(Array(serverEntries) as [ServerEntry], id: \.id, children: \.children) { entry in
                Text(entry.title)
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol ListEntry: Identifiable {
    var id: ObjectIdentifier { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var children: [any ListEntry]? { get }
}

extension ServerEntry: ListEntry {
    var title: String {
        return self.name ?? ""
    }
    
    var children: [any ListEntry]? {
        return self.folders?.allObjects as! [FolderEntry]
    }
}

extension FolderEntry: ListEntry {
    var title: String {
        return self.name ?? ""
    }
    
    var children: [any ListEntry]? {
        return nil
    }
}
```